# Php: $var != NULL not working remote server

Tags: php, mysql

i've created an advanced search page for my site. All works when i run on localhost but when i upload the same page on remote server there's a condition in php which does not work.

My idea is that if in the form nothing is compiled user get all products using

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
```

When unless one of input is filled with something it adds the WHERE clause and the part of the query i need.

This is my code:

```
public function fetch_this($a, $b, $c, $d){
        $search_connection = new Search_connection();//connect to database
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
        if ((isset($a) && $a!= NULL) or (isset($b) && $b!= NULL) 
            or (isset($c) && $c!= NULL) or (isset($d) && $d!= NULL)){
            $query.=" WHERE ";
        }
        $contatore = 0;

        if(isset($a) && $a!= NULL){
            $query.= "((a<= '$a' and b>= '$a') or a LIKE '$a')";
            $counter++; 
        }


            //... same for b c d 

           $search_connection->connetti();
           $res = mysql_query($query);
           return $res;
}
```

Initially i used !empty instead of (isset($a) && $a!= NULL) but i need to get '0' in input and empty() returned me true instead of searching 0.

I already tried `is_null(), !==NULL, !=false, !$a` ecc but nothing works.

Any advice?

I can't understand why it works in localhost but not in remote server, php version is the same.

Thanks!

EDIT 1:

if i vardump ($a) when i leacve it unfilled i get this:

```
localhost: string(0) ""
remoteserver: bool(false)
```

If i put 0 in input:

```
localhost: string(1) "0"
remoteserver:bool(false)
```

Here is the problem.

The code which launch the function is this:

```
$a= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['a']);
    $b= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['b']);
    $c= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['c']);
    $d= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['d']);

    $res = $single_query->fetch_this($a, $b, $c, $d);
```

Comment: You will need to debug this yourself at least up to a point. What does `var_dump($a)` say?

Comment: What exactly do you want to check for? "Parameter is set and is not an empty string"?

Comment: 0 is empty '' is also empty array() is also empty

Comment: Someone generous answer that!!

Comment: i need to check if input is set. The problem is that isset() always say TRUE cause i have text input but i need to work with numbers. If i use empty() functions it works correctly but if the user post 0 empty returns true instead of false

Comment: If only you could use two conditions.

Comment: I already have my solution, but on remote server it does not work. Anybody can tell me why? i get bool(false) from vardump when i check my input even if it's empty or zero or whatever

Comment: Are you using the same browser in both tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isset` returns false if NULL so second condition is unnecessary.

But isset returns true if empty string, so check for that instead.

```
 if ( isset($a) && $a != '')
```

### Update:

You could simply go a different approach and check the value in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
('$a' <> '' AND 
( (a <= '$a' AND b >= '$a') OR a LIKE '$a')
);
```

Now if the search parameter is blank or NULL, it will short-circuit the WHERE clause when

`'$a' <> ''`

returns false.

Answer (score -3):

simply try this

`if(isset($a) || ($a!= NULL)){`

Comment: If `$a` is `null` then `isset` is `false`.